# Majorization and Schur Polynomials

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, rt.representation-theory, schur-functions, partitions, open-problems

Let me first define the majorization order (or dominance order) on partitions as $\lambda \succeq \mu$ iff $$\sum _{i=1}^{k}\lambda_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^{k}\mu_i$$ for all $1\le k\le l-1$ and $$\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_l=\mu_1+\cdots+\mu_l.$$

While playing around with some variation on [Muirhead's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) which says that
$$m_{\lambda}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\geq m_{\mu}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$ for all $x_i\geq 0$ when $\lambda \succeq \mu$ (here the $m_{\lambda}$'s are the monomial symmetric polynomials) I ended up investigating if such an inequality holds for Schur polynomials, which are another famous basis of the ring of symmetric functions. I tried a few special cases, and the following seems to hold, but I don't have a proof or a counterexample. So the question is:

> Let $x_1,\dots,x_n \geq 0$ and $\lambda\succeq \mu$, is it always true that $$\frac{s _{\lambda}(x _1,x _2,\dots,x _n)}{s _{\lambda}(1,1,\dots,1)}\geq \frac{s _{\mu}(x _1,x _2,\dots,x _n)}{s _{\mu}(1,1,\dots,1)}?$$

If not, does majorization induce some similarly nice order on values of Schur polynomials?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to introduce a second set of variables, and look at double Schur functions as well...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question is listed as a conjecture (conjecture 7.4 in the section "Open questions") in a recent [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WDY-526CFXB-3&_user=10&_coverDate=02%2F17%2F2011&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=gateway&_origin=gateway&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=f28d84462f1b0537df2951b5fd44de42&searchtype=a) of Cuttler, Greene and Skandera.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to wait till tomorrow to gain access to the paper. About a year ago I had proofs for the corresponding inequalities on elementary, complete or power symmetric functions, and I thought I had proved the inequality in the OP as well, but I had made a few silly mistakes. I guess now I'm less hopeful that it can be fixed (i.e. that it can be approached by elementary methods)...

Comment: FYI, there are several online versions on author's pages, e.g. http://www.haverford.edu/math/cgreene/papers/smean10-15.pdf - in case you don't care if you get the journal version.

Comment: Oh no, that's perfect. It looks like an interesting read!

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/j.ejc.2011.01.020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2011.01.020) ([Zbl 1229.05267](https://zbmath.org/1229.05267)).

Answer (score 12):

This was recently proven by Suvrit Sra, [on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04753). (Make sure to read version 3.)

Answer (score 1):

This was also subsequently proved by Rachid Ait-Haddou and Marie-Laurence Mazure in 2018 in [FOCM](http://doi.org/10.1007/s10208-016-9334-8). There's also a variant in a [preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1708.05197) by Apoorva Khare and Terence Tao (see latest version) with "majorization" replaced by "weak majorization" and "all $x_i \geq 0$" replaced by "all $x_i \geq 1$".